# Big-$O$ complexity of $n(m+1)$.

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I have an algorithm that takes $n(m+1)$ operations, where $n$ and $m$ are non-negative values. What is the complexity of this algorithm in Big-$O$ notation? I feel tempted to say $O(n(m+1))$ because $(m+1)$ is always positive, and if you say $O(nm)$, then if m is zero $mn$ is zero even as n tends to infinity, so it doesn't describe the asymptotic complexity when $m = 0$, which would be $O(n)$ for $n(m+1)$.

Comment: It would just be $O(nm)$. The cases where $n$ or $m$ are zero are irrelevant to asymptotic analysis (i.e. the runtime for large $n, m$).

Comment: You have a similar question in another post, so I don't want to answer and get downvoted without a reason once again. m does not need to be zero for the pathological case to happen. m can be a fractional value between 0 and 1 even. In that case also 1 cannot be ignored in comparison with m. It really is just common sense. Anyway, for whatever it is worth, I think I know what I am talking about. I'll leave it to you to see reason.